# Composer update missing extension ext-apache *

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, wampserver

[image]

This is my EVN:

- Windows 10
- Composer version 1.8.0
- php version 7.2.13
- wampserver version 3.1.4

Answer (score 3):

I found that the problem comes from PhpStorm(2018.3) suggestion to add the extension

[image]

[image]

So after I comment or remove them, it works fine for me,

          `"webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"//,
//        "ext-apache": "*",
//        "ext-curl": "*"`

Comment: How did you manage to comment out a part of JSON file (Composer configuration)? The very same PhpStorm, when pasting your example code, marks it as an error with following explanation: "JSON standard does not allow comments. Use JSMin or similar tool to remove comments before parsing".